# Assign a case to a queue in Apex (Test class)

Tags: apex, failing-tests, queue

I'm sure this must be quite possible, and probably easy.

I need to create a test method in which part of the scenario is that for when a **Case** is assigned to a **Queue**. I have successfully tested all my scenarios where Cases are owned by Users, but I cannot work out how to programmatically assign my test case to a queue.

The core of my test method currently creates a test queue and (simplified snippet) sticks a case in, owned by this queue; like so:

```
Group testGroup = new Group(Name='test group', type='Queue');
insert testGroup;

QueuesObject testQueue = new QueueSObject(QueueID = testGroup.id, SobjectType = 'Case');
insert testQueue;

Case aCase = new Case(OwnerId = testQueue.Id);

Insert aCase;
```

This then goes on to do a load of testing, but when I run the test, I get the error message:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Owner ID: id value of incorrect type: 03gf00000001X2RAAU: [OwnerId]

On the insert of the case.

Now, we know Cases can be owned by Users or Queues (snippet here from the case field list)

[image: case owner field]

but apparantly, this Id cannot be set to a Queue? (and you cannot directly set the Owner field, you get a "Field is not writeable" error at compile time).

Can someone help me out here? Cheers.

Comment: Is assignment rule doing this in real scenario?

Comment: Nope, we do have assignment rules, but they are just to users. The assignment of cases to queues is performed manually in live.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than setting the Case.OwnerId to the Queue ID you need to set it to the Group ID. As OwnerId is a lookup to User and Group rather than User and Queue as displayed in the UI.

You can check it yourself using [Workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com) **> Info > Standard & Custom Objects > Case**, **Fields > OwnerId > Reference To**.

[image: Workbench]

However by doing this you will receive a `MIXED_DML_EXCEPTION`  due to executing DML on a setup object (inserting `QueuesObject`) between DML on non-setup objects (`Group` and `Case`) to get around this you need to execute the DML on setup objects in a different context, this can be done using `System.runAs(...)`.

If you change it to the following it should work:

```
Group testGroup = new Group(Name='test group', Type='Queue');
insert testGroup;

System.runAs(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId()))
{
    QueuesObject testQueue = new QueueSObject(QueueID = testGroup.id, SObjectType = 'Case');
    insert testQueue;
}

Case aCase = new Case(OwnerId = testGroup.Id);
insert aCase;
```

Comment: hmm. ok, interesting! I'll give that a whirl. Weird that it takes a group Id, but is a lookup to queue - must be something to do with sObject hierarchy? Don't suppose you can shed any light on what/why the runAs is needed?!

Comment: @SimonLawrence I've edited my answer to include the answers to your questions.