# Getting INVALID_OPERATION, Queue not associated with this SObject type: [] on Assigning Cases to a Queue in Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, queue

I was writing a Test class to test a scenario where the Case will be assigned to Queue. However when I am assigning a Case Object to a Queue I am getting this error-
"INVALID_OPERATION, Queue not associated with this SObject type: []"

I have created a Group and also mapped it to Case Object using QueueSObject but still facing this error.

```
User currentTestUser = [Select id from User where id = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
Group testGroup = new Group(Name='testGroup',type='Queue');
insert testGroup;
    
System.runAs(currentTestUser){
    QueuesObject testQueue = new QueueSObject(QueueID = testGroup.id, SobjectType = 'Case');
    insert testQueue;             
}
```

Comment: Are you getting error in this code block??

Comment: Why are you creating a queue in your test?  Doesn't it already exist?

Comment: Aside from the first line being irrelevant and wasteful, this approach should work.

Comment: When I am assigning this Queue to a case then I am getting this error @Pmanglani

Comment: Have you checked this one https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/33457/56744